# How to determine if speech recognition is supported on a device?

Tags: android

It appears most speech-recognition example just create and run an intent. If the intent throws an exception, they pop up a message that speech-recognition doesn't work on the device.

In my app, I would like to display a mic button next to text input. However, I don't want to display the button if the device does not support speech recognition.

Is there a way to find if speech-recognition is supported? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable();

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

Comment: @Peter This does not work in the general case, e.g. if the speech recognizer does not implement the `RecognitionService` interface. In short, if you are calling the recognizer _activity_, then you should check if the intent resolves to this activity, not check if some service is available. See my answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

As with any intent, you can call [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to find out if the intent resolves to any activities, in this case speech recognition activities.

If you are using the speech recognizer via the service then you can call [isRecognitionAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#isRecognitionAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) (as already pointed out by EJK).