# Android 13 Call recording both sides

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, call-recording

From Android 10, I have to use Accessibility access and you can record a call using MediaRecorder with the source voice recognition. The problem is that on some devices the recording is not both ways - there is only one voice.

This is the basic implementation with MediaRecorder:

```
MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder(); 
recorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC); 
recorder.prepare(); Thread.sleep(2000); recorder.start();
```

I tested Cube ACR from Google play. They have an option to set the audio source to "voice recognition software". If this is enabled, you can get both sides of the conversation.

I did not find something on the Internet related to "voice recognition software". Does anyone know how to do this? - maybe a github project

Does anyone have a solution about recording both parts of the conversation that works on the new versions of Android ? Android 12 or Android 13.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I need a similar code, but it dont need work on all devices. If it works on some newer versions of the Android API, 12 for example, that's great for me. It's just for testing. I couldn't get one that works both ways.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Cube ACR seems to have the same issue. See: https://cube-call-recorder-acr.en.softonic.com/android . In the "cons" they say:

> In some instances two-way audio may not be recorded

See also this stackoverflow question: [How to determine if speech recognition is supported on a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551511/how-to-determine-if-speech-recognition-is-supported-on-a-device)

Answer (score 0):

you can give this a try as well to automate record call recording even from whtsapp
https://play.google.com/store/apps/datasafety?id=com.sparklingapps.callrecorder